# php-fpm creating directory as root

Tags: php-fpm

I'm running php-fpm, and I'm having a problem that sometimes my code will create a directory as the root user, even though all the php-fpm processes are running as nginx.

The master process itself is running as root, so I suspect that process is the one creating these root-owned directories.

Does anyone have any solutions to this issue?

Comment: can you check that you do not have g+s set on your webroot if it is owned by root group?

Comment: This isn't the log file, is it?

Comment: No, it's a file in the file system.  There's no sticky bit set.

Comment: Does "my code" refer to a PHP script that runs via PHP-FPM? Any chance on showing more details on that code?

Comment: I figured out the issue - another script was running as root elsewhere causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another script running via cron was running as the root user, which was creating the directories as root.  It wasn't related to PHP-FPM at all.